# Есть ли у JS скриптов зависимость от версии php на сервере?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт, раньше он работал на php 5.3, а сейчас обновился до 5.6 и в итоге в одном скрипте при запросе (обработки) просто белый экран, в другом не обрабатывает вовсе.

Comment: Нет, js никак не зависит от PHP..

Comment: хм... спасибо. Значит буду ковырять сам код php

Answer (score 0):

Если не изменяет память, начиная с версии PHP5.5 модуль json удален из поставки php и устанавливается отдельно. Стоит посмотреть в логах p`PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()`

Если такая ошибка есть, то доставить php5-json

Второй вариант - изменился синтаксис.

> 5.6.0 Недопустимые варианты true, false и null не в нижнем регистре больше не принимают в качестве допустимого ввода и будут генерировать предупреждения.
>   5.4.0   Был добавлен параметр options.

Comment: Хм, при чём тут вообще `JSON` на сервере?

Comment: Насколько я понял, JSON оправляется на сервер и обрабатывается PHP (раньше 5.3, теперь 5.6) Может топикстартер прояснит этот вопрос

Comment: В вопросе вообще нет намёка на JSON. Предположения надо выяснять в комментариях.

Comment: Ребят спасибо, сам разобрался уже. Ошибка была в том, что у меня в php были устаревшие функции. Обновил и все стало отлично работать